# Ubuntu 16.04 Gnome software does not list all apps

Tags: 16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04,the new software app does not list all application available to install. For example the software app does not show the game wesnoth in the list.But when I use Synaptic package manager it shows it.Similar in the case of geany-plugins any many others.how to solve the problem

Comment: I noticed the same problem. came here for a solution

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1589970), have to wait until it is resolved.